# How to process requests and cookies using C++ wtih NGINX?

Tags: c++, performance, iis, nginx

We are planning on migrating from IIS to Nginx to gain performance. Our web layer is very lightweight - for each request we are reading/setting cookies and perform some very quick data cleanup and passing it down to very fast storage (Aerospike). Most of the requests take under 100ms, but we are experiencing inefficiencies due to IIS binding thread to each request. We are processing A LOT of concurrent requests.

Whats the best way to accomplish the same thing in Nginx? I know it would probably make sense to C++ to do most of my processing. Where do I take care of cookies, can I do it with C++? How do I forward a request from Nginx down to a compiled C++ binary effectively.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a module in nginx. The basic module should be written in C. But I guess you will be able write the main workhorse functions in c++. Unfortunately the api for module development etc is not documented well but Evan Millers [Guide](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html) is your best guide.